# I'm looking for a movie with a kid named Max training to be a soldier

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The movie was about a kid named Max who was training to be a soldier for some massive government. Aliens had invaded the Earth in the movie, and the kid was stranded on an alien planet after his ship went down.  It had one of those aliens as cargo. He is hunted down by the alien, and in the end he kills it. I also vaguely remember a scene where he is dreaming about his mom, and she turns into a zombie while she screams "wake up Max."

Can anyone identify this movie?

Comment: Hi, what's "a long time", 5 years, 10, 15, 20? Was it English language, an Amreican Production, British? Was it live action or animated? Was it non English language and dubbed? What did the spaceships look like? What did the alien look like? Was it CGI, puppet, stop motion or a guy in a monster suit? Please add anything you can remember, the more unusual the better.

Comment: And how old was Max "the kid"? 5? 12? 17?

Comment: Outlander (2008) has similar premise. As well as After Earth, with Jaden and Will Smith.